# How to style navbar for profile section

Tags: css, angular

I currently have an angular app that has a nav bar made up of a tags, now when the player logs in i have an `ngIf` for a my profile icon to show with dropdowns but I cant get it styled correctly, I just want sort of that spanner icon on the top right of the nav bar and when clicked it shows options. This is what I have so far:

```html
<div class="page-links responsive" [ngClass]="{'animate': shouldShow}">
  <a [routerLink]="''"
     [routerLinkActive]="'active'"
     [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"
     draggable="false"
     (click)="toggleMenu()">
    Home
  </a>
  <a [routerLink]="'/university'"
     [routerLinkActive]="'active'"
     draggable="false"
     (click)="toggleMenu()">
    University Cup
  </a>
  <a [routerLink]="'/rules'"
     [routerLinkActive]="'active'"
     draggable="false"
     (click)="toggleMenu()">
    The Game
  </a>
  <a [routerLink]="'/tournaments'"
     [routerLinkActive]="'active'"
     draggable="false"
     (click)="toggleMenu()">
    Tournaments
  </a>
  <a [routerLink]="'/history'"
     [routerLinkActive]="'active'"
     draggable="false"
     (click)="toggleMenu()">
    Our Legacy
  </a>
  <a [routerLink]="'/team'"
     [routerLinkActive]="'active'"
     draggable="false"
     (click)="toggleMenu()">
    Our Team
  </a>
  <a [routerLink]="'/portal'"
     [routerLinkActive]="'active'"
     draggable="false"
     (click)="toggleMenu()">
    Player Portal
</a>
  <a *ngIf="isAuthed">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label><mat-icon>accessibility</mat-icon></mat-label>
      <mat-select>
        <mat-option value="option1">My Profile</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="option2">GitHub Instructions</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="option3">Download CICD file</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="option4">Logout</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </a>
</div>
```

My css:

```css
    .page-links {
  @media (max-width: $screen-md-max) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
    padding: 0 8px;
    margin: 0 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition-property: height, border-width, underline, background-color, color;
    transition: ease-in-out 350ms;
    font-weight: bold;

    &, &:active, &:focus, &:visited {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
    }

    &:hover {
      color: $title;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    }

    &.active {
      color: $title;
    }
  }

  li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
    padding: 0 8px;
    margin: 0 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition-property: height, border-width, underline, background-color, color;
    transition: ease-in-out 350ms;
    font-weight: bold;

    &, &:active, &:focus, &:visited {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: grey;
    }

  }

  &.responsive {
    @media (max-width: $screen-md-max) {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      background: $primary-darker;

      a {
        position: relative;
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        height: 0;
        line-height: 50px;
        padding: 0 16px;
        margin: 0;
        border-top: 0 solid white;
      }

      li {
        position: relative;
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        height: 0;
        line-height: 50px;
        padding: 0 16px;
        margin: 0;
        border-top: 0 solid white;
      }

      &.animate {
        a {
          height: 50px;
          border-width: 1px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But my code renders like this:
[Rendered Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBYe8.png)

What can i do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please add two more div's and add independent classes. and format  by using the CSS it will work

```
    <div class="left-menu">
        <a>Home</a>
        <a>University Cup</a>
        <a>The Game</a>
        <a>Tournaments</a>
        <a>Our Legacy </a>
        <a>Our Team</a>
        <a>Player Portal</a>
    </div>
    <div class="right-menu">
        <a *ngIf="isAuthed">
            <mat-form-field></mat-form-field>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .left-menu{
        float: left;
        width:80%;
    }
    .right-menu {
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
    }
</style>
```